# Android "Nearby" ( set up nearby device ) - "No devices Found"

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, 7.0-nougat, 9.0-pie, setup-wizard

trying to migrate over from  1 mobile to other . Older is on 7.0 and newer is 9.x aka `Pie`. 

Both devices have `bluetooth` and `wi-fi` turned on. In fact one sees the other on a bluetooth scan and they are paired.

Its just that the `nearby` service (?) of whatever its called that is used  for setting up a new device just doesn't do its job.
I initiated  simultaneously from both phone - the "find nearby devices" beacon...none of the phones "found " each other . I repeated the same separately- No avail.

Why is this happening and what does it take for this stuff to run correctly ?